# Wordpress Plugin default option

Tags: plugin-development, settings-api

i'm working on a plugin and i got a checkbox with the setting code:

```
    register_setting('plugin551-setting-group', 'livechat_option');
```

I want it to be default true, the checkbox in the setting page is now default false.
How can i do this?

Comment: any research effort at all? I think this question is asked about once a month :(

Comment: I did research, can you link me this question?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18047629/wordpress-settings-page-how-to-default-the-state-of-a-checkbox-to-checked

Comment: It is really that checkbox issues are the oldest gotcha in php. the lack of any attempt to figure it out by yourself is why the downvote and comment. If you meant to ask if there is anything special in the setting API for it, than the answer would have been a simple no.

Answer (score 0):

```
$default_data = Array(
    "plugin551-setting-group"   => Array(
        'checkboxoption1'       =>  'true',
        'checkboxoption2'       =>  'true'
    )
);

if ( is_admin() && isset($_GET['activate'] ) && $pagenow == 'plugins.php' ){
    global $default_data;
    plugin551_save_settings($default_data);
}

function plugin551_save_settings ( $data ) {    
    if( isset( $data['plugin551-setting-group'] )){
        array_walk_recursive( $data['plugin551-setting-group'] , 'plugin551_clean_options');
        update_option( 'plugin551-setting-group' ,  $data['plugin551-setting-group']   );
    }
}

function plugin551_clean_options(&$value) {
  $value = htmlspecialchars(stripslashes($value));
}
```

Comment: This isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you are activating the plugin, store the value of checkbox as checked in the database.

You can then retrieve the value of checkbox from database.